# What kind of metal alloys can resist corrosion from molten salt?

Tags: alloy

Molten salt is pretty hot, 801 C. With such heat and the corrosive nature of salt, I am wondering what type of metal alloy or other material hybrid would be appropriate to handle and work with molten salt?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

George Lai's *High-Temperature Corrosion and Materials Applications* (excerpts available on [Google Books](http://books.google.ca/books?id=tfDwOe7xWeQC&pg=PA409&dq=george+lai+molten+salt+corrosion&hl=en&sa=X&ei=b7qxU_nOAYKqyATn-IGQAw&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=george%20lai%20molten%20salt%20corrosion&f=false)) is a good source. Very often for molten salts, Hastelloys are used; they're special-purpose alloys developed by [Haynes International](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hastelloy#Hastelloy). I can't find a reference, but I believe Oak Ridge National Laboratories used Hastelloys for their molten salt reactors (which had fluoride salts, very reactive).

If you're working with sodium chloride (little potassium), according to Lai, [Hastelloy-188](http://www.hightempmetals.com/techdata/hitempHaynes188data.php) seems to be the best bet, although many others would work as well. One reality of chemical engineering is that there will always be corrosion, it's just a matter of keeping it at an acceptable rate for the application.

Comment: Oh wow, they did a heat exchange and everything, which is very relevant to my interests. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use tungsten as it has the highest and best melting point among all the stable metallic elements its melting point is nearly [$3700~\mathrm{K}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melting_point)

More over its [price](http://www.infomine.com/investment/metal-prices/ferro-tungsten/) is also considerably lower than other metals with higher melting points and if you think of corrosive nature, then I would recommend you to use silver but it becomes very [costly](http://www.postalbullion.com/silver-price-per-grams-week-gbp-5.aspx).

Feel free to comment for further clarification. I will definitely help you.